# jQuery - prev/next navigation between non-siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of elements of the same type that have different parents, but I would like to be able to seamlessly navigate/cycle through all of them as if they were together.

```
<div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#" class="open></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>

<div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>

<div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>

<a href="#" class="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a href="#" class="next">&rsaquo;</a>
```

I've managed to get this far: https://jsfiddle.net/pj0ecxge/

Currently it doesn't function as intended, as prev() and next() are only meant to target sibling elements, so the arrows don't work if the previous or next element is in another parent.

A single element will always be open by default, but it won't always be the same element as shown in the example. Also, only one element can be open at the same time.

If it makes a difference, I can add a single class to all children elements, but I can't change the HTML structure i.e put them all inside the same parent.

It would be nice if the navigation is infinite - i.e clicking next while the last element is open will show the first element and vice versa, but this is not required if it's too complex to do.

Thanks in advance and any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the next set when the current set has reached either end. And the if the set is the last one then go back to the first one (and vice-versa).

```
$('.prev').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var current = $('.open');
    var prev = current.prev();
    if (!prev.length) {
        prev = current.parent().prev('div').children('a:last-of-type');
        if (!prev.length) {
            prev = $('div:last-of-type').children('a:last-of-type');
        }
    }

    current.removeClass('open');
    prev.addClass('open');
});

$('.next').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var current = $('.open');
    var next = current.next();

    if (!next.length) {
        next = current.parent().next('div').children('a:first-of-type');   
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $('div:first-of-type').children('a:first-of-type');
        }
    }

    current.removeClass('open');
    next.addClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether there are next/previous elements, if not then you can move a layer up/down like

```js
$('.prev').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var current = $('.open');
  var prev = current.prev();

  if (!prev.length) {
    prev = current.parent().prev('div').children('a:last-child')
  }

  if (prev.length) {
    current.removeClass('open');
    prev.addClass('open');
  }
});

$('.next').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var current = $('.open');
  var next = current.next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = current.parent().next('div').children('a:first-child')
  }

  if (next.length) {
    current.removeClass('open');
    next.addClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  font-size: 0;
}
div a {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.open {
  background: red;
}
.prev,
.next {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#" class="open"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>

<a href="#" class="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a href="#" class="next">&rsaquo;</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very fast answer! You were first, but Griffith also covered the bonus requirement, so I've accepted his answer.